# fatal error Function name must be a string

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get comments from users but the browser says Fatal error: Function name must be a string. My code;

```
// <form name="form1" method="post" action="posting.php">
// <input name="comment" type="text" id="comment" style="width:254px; height:44px;">
// </form>

<?php

  $comment = $_POST('comment');//this was the line where problem occured

  if(!empty($comment))
  {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO comment (comment) VALUES('".$comment."')");
  }

  echo "$comment";

?>
```

Answer (score 9):

Array dereferences are performed with brackets: `[` and `]`. So....

```
$comment = $_POST['comment'];
```

Answer (score 2):

You used parentheses after `$_POST` when you wanted square brackets.

Answer (score 2):

```
$_POST['comment'];
```

Square brackets instead of parenthesis.

Comment: Life saving suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

Probably

```
  $_POST['comment']
```

instead of ('comment'). Btw: make sure you escape this, unless you don't care about SQL injection / XSS attack

Comment: instead of $comment = $_POST['comment'] I would write $comment = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comment']). Then when you display it ensure you can for example wrap it in htmlentities() method. Probably it is not sufficient, but better than nothing

Answer (score 0):

> Use $_POST['comment'] instead of $_POST('comment');